# make indent for hyperlink in CSS

Tags: html, css

how can i make an indent for hyperlink ?
 I've tried as this code but no success.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#h"> html </a>
```

Comment: there are many ways to do this

Comment: what if you don't want to indent all hrefs?

Comment: have you tried padding-left:20px ?

Comment: yes i want to indent the first href just.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want all hyperlinks to be indented, you could wrap it around a `<div>` with a unique id; this is an alternate solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="indented">
    <a href="#h"> html </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#indented {

    text-indent:20px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you .. I've tried it and the result is correct

Answer (score 0):

text-indent is not avalaible for inline elements

> https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-indent

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 20px;/* not avalaible for inline elements */  
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#h"> html </a>
```

padding could help

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 20px;/* not avalaible for inline elements */  
  padding-left:20px;;
}
```

```html
<a href="#h"> html </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a CSS file and link it to your HTML file using the link tag:

```
    a {
      text-decoration:none;
      text-indent:20px;
    }
```

My strong suggestion is go with the CSS file, it's a lot cleaner and allows you to target more elements, not just that specific anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent` is for block or inline-block elements. So you can assign `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to the `a` tag and get the desired effect. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRvOQd